# Synchronizing transformation of a Rect class between CPU and GPU

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics

I implemented a `Rect` class in my custom game engine that utilizes openGL. I decided to approach the whole `Rect` class design like Unity's [implementation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html).

Essentially, what I do is I directly manipulate the X and Y coordinates of the rectangle and also its width and height and then I update the Vertex Buffer Object using the following function `glBufferSubData(GLenum target, GLintptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid* data)`.

Here is my design:

```
class Rect
{
private:
    VertexArray* vao = nullptr;
    VertexBuffer* vbo = nullptr;
    IndexBuffer* ibo = nullptr;
private:
    real* dataBuffer = nullptr;
    uint32* indicesBuffer = nullptr;
private:
    real x, y;
    real width, height;
    real xMax, yMax;
public:
    Rect(real x, real y, real width, real height);
    ~Rect();
public:
    void SetX(real x);
    void SetY(real y);
    void SetWidth(real width);
    void SetHeight(real height);
    void SetUV(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2, Vector2 v3, Vector2 v4);
    real GetX();
    real GetY();
    real GetWidth();
    real GetHeight();
    std::vector<Vector2> GetUV();
    Vector2 GetCenter();
public:
    bool Contains(Vector2 point);
public:
    void Bind();
    void UnBind();
};
```

Now the issue occurs when I multiply the rectangle's Vertex Buffer Object with model matrix which causes the actual vertex data inside the GPU to change but the `Rect` object data remains the same inside the CPU **(The rectangle could be at coordiantes (100,250) but the X and Y coordinates stored in the object are (50, 50))** which will cause all kind of issues especially when performing hit testing for UI or picking up GameObjects.

How can I approach such a problem while remaining true to Unity's design.

Comment: Wouldn't the UI hit test transform the ray from view space into world space to match the rect's CPU-side coordinate system?

Comment: I haven't figured out that yet, I'm more concerned with figuring out how to update the CPU data when GLSL performs matrix multiplication on the rect's vertices.